# GCE instance does not get permissions from service acount

Tags: google-compute-engine, service-accounts, google-iam

I'm trying to set up read/write access to a Cloud Storage bucket from a GCE instance, using a service account, but don't get the permissions. I have done the following:

- Created service account, let's say 'my-sa'
- Created a bucket, let's say 'my-bucket'
- In IAM console for my project, assign role 'Cloud Storage admin' to service account
- Created a new GCE instance via the console, assigned to service account 'my-sa'. Access scope is then automatically set to cloud-platform
- Connect to instance using gcloud compute ssh as my user (project owner)
- Run gsutil ls gs://my-bucket

*Expected behaviour*: get list of items in bucket

*Observed behaviour*:

gsutil takes about 5 seconds to think, then gives:
AccessDeniedException: 403 my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket my-bucket.

Things I've tried:

- gcloud auth list on the instance does show the service account, and shows it as being active
- I've added more permissions to the service account (up to project owner), doesn't make a difference
- I also can't use other permissions from the instance. When I give Compute Engine Admin role to the service account, I can't run gcloud compute instances list from the instance
- I've removed the .gsutil dir to make sure the cache is cleared
- With the default Compute Engine service account, I can list the buckets, but not write (as expected). When I add the Cloud Storage read/write access scope from the console, I can also write

I really don't have a clue on how to debug this anymore, so any help would be much apprreciated

Comment: Following your steps worked for me. I am only able to get the same error if I type the wrong bucket while running "gsutil ls gs://my-bucket". Can you verify there was not a typo on that step?

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying. I'm sure the bucket name is correct. I'll try to reproduce on a new project

Comment: Hi Davy .. Did you able to solve this issue. I am struck with this exact issue .  Even ```ping api.google.com``` has no luck . Network wise using default network and no restrictions . Even thing works great with default compute engine account.

Comment: The problem occurred as we have disabled the external IP and the default network  is not enabled with private access to GCP services . Once enabled every thing worked as expected . https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options